# What is the execution order of recursive datalog?

Tags: recursion, datalog

```
Q(a, b) :- Edge(a, b).
Q(a, b) :- Q(a, x),
            Edge(x, b).
```

The function of this code is to search all pair of nodes which are reachable. How is that recursive?

Comment: That's some weird datalog- The predicate names are uppercase, and the variable names are lowercase. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is recursive because the predicate calls itself:

```
q(A, B) :- q(A, X),edge(X, B).
```

What the actual execution order is depends on the implementation. It may be "bottom up":

- From any `edge(A,B)` derive `q(A,B)`
- Apply `q(A, B) :- q(A, X),edge(X, B).` until a fixpoint has been reached (i.e. not further `q(A,B)` can be deduced).

owever, you should be able to rearrange the code without being at risk of generating non-termination search, unlike in Prolog.

This should work too:

```
q(A, B) :- q(A, X),edge(X, B).
q(A, B) :- edge(A, B).
```